# Input a KML file dynamically into MapServer without losing attributes?

Tags: convert, kml, mapserver, tab

Is there any possibility for MapServer (I'm running v6.2.1) to process the features / styles from a KML file dynamically?

I tried STYLEITEM "AUTO" but it turned out to work only for *.dgn and *.tab files. Actually this'd be exactly the kind of feature I'm looking for tho.

Alternatively i'm searching for a way to get my KML file converted to *.tab (MapInfo) in order to later auto-feed it to MapServer. I tried using ogr2ogr but this always results in losing all the attributes from the KML file, leaving only the coordinates with the geometry.